# how to call private method in test class to acheive code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
//Method returns last date of fiscal year
private date getFiscalLastDate(){
        Integer currentFY;
        Integer currentFYMonth;
        Integer CurrentFYDays;
        Date today;
        Date FYStartDate;
        Date FYEndDate;

        Organization orgInfo = [SELECT FiscalYearStartMonth, UsesStartDateAsFiscalYearName
                                FROM Organization
                                WHERE id=:Userinfo.getOrganizationId()];

        today = system.today();
        currentFYMonth = orgInfo.FiscalYearStartMonth;

        if (today.month() >= orgInfo.FiscalYearStartMonth) {
            if (orgInfo.UsesStartDateAsFiscalYearName) {
                currentFY = today.year();
            } 
            else {
            currentFY = today.year() + 1;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (orgInfo.UsesStartDateAsFiscalYearName) {
                    currentFY = today.year() - 1;
            }
            else {
                currentFY = today.year();
            }
        }

        CurrentFYDays = date.daysInMonth(currentFY, currentFYMonth);

        FYStartDate = date.parse(CurrentFYMonth + '/' + '01' + '/' + currentFY);
        FYStartDate = FYStartDate.addYears(-1);
        FYEndDate = FYStartDate.addYears(1).addDays(-1);
        return FYEndDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use @TestVisible to call this method otherwise best pracctice is try to cover those lines which are calling this method that will also cover these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the above answers regarding `@testVisible` are correct, **I don't think it's good practice to explicitly call a private method in a test**. There is a reason why the method private, and it's generally because it should not be called from the outside as it may leave your object in an incorrect state.

I agree with @TusharSharma that the best practice is to test the public methods, and as long as those public methods call your private method, your private method will be covered.

In general, you don't need to aim for >75% code coverage. But if you need to, you have to make sure that your tests cover all branches. In your particular case, you have several `if` conditions that yield 4 possible execution paths inside your code. You will need 4 different tests to cover all 4 cases.

The `if` statements depend on the value of `system.today()` (which you cannot mock in a test method) and `orgInfo`, which you could. You can try to change the values of the `orgInfo` record in the database, if it's a read/write object. Or, you could refactor your private method to take the orgInfo object as an argument, make that object a private, test-visible member, and change it in your tests to exercise all 4 cases.

Comment: I understand the idea of testing private methods by just testing the public methods that call them, but in scenarios where the private method contains pretty complex logic, it can be handy to test that complexity at the finest level, then the calling public method can be tested at a more broader level.

Answer (score 1):

Use Annotation TestVisible for private mthod. Using this annotation private method is visible to Test class only.
For more details use below link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the mehod with @testVisible:

> Use the TestVisible annotation to allow test methods to access private or protected members of another class outside the test class. These members include methods, member variables, and inner classes. This annotation enables a more permissive access level for running tests only. This annotation doesn’t change the visibility of members if accessed by non-test classes.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm)